# illustrator javascript export jpg spaces replaced by a dash

Tags: javascript, export, jpeg, adobe-illustrator

I wrote a script to export the file to jpeg. However, when exporting, if the file name contains spaces, these are replaced by a dash. Why? If you export from Illustrator in a manual, then the file name is displayed correctly. If you use fileJpg.saveDlg('');, dialgoue window shows correctly the file name, but keeps replacing spaces with dashes.

```
function ExportJpgFunction(){
    var exportOptions = new ExportOptionsJPEG();
    var type = ExportType.JPEG;
    var fileJpg = new File('D:\\for Jpg and Eps/' + myWindow.fnamePanel.fileNameText.text + '.jpg');
    fileJpg.saveDlg('');     
    exportOptions.antiAliasing = true;
    exportOptions.qualitySetting = 100;
    exportOptions.verticalScale = 420;
    exportOptions.horizontalScale = 420;
    app.activeDocument.exportFile( fileJpg, type, exportOptions );
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zj5s.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple workaround, just rename file with dashes, add this rows at the end of your code:

```
var fileJpg1 = new File("c:\\tmp\\for-Jpg-and-Eps.jpg");//path to file with dashes
fileJpg1.rename('for Jpg and Eps.jpg');
```

Comment: On the contrary. I write the file name without the dashes, and illustrator when you export adds a dash. I added a image that would be clear.

Comment: You misunderstood me, I suggested that you rename file after the  illustrator saved it with that dased name using rename function.

Answer (score 0):

this is the bug in Illustrator scripting. To remove this you have to replace manually.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by others, this is a bug/quirk of Adobe Illustrator.

I worked around the same problem by removing the dashes from the file names AFTER Adobe Illustrator creates them.

```html
renameFile ('D:\\for Jpg and Eps/' + replaceSpacesWithDashes(myWindow.fnamePanel.fileNameText.text) + '.jpg', myWindow.fnamePanel.fileNameText.text + '.jpg');
  
function replaceSpacesWithDashes (stringToDash) {
    
    //Simulate dashed up files from undashed original 
    var dashedString = stringToDash.replace(/\s+/g, "-");

    return dashedString;

}
  
function renameFile (fileFromPath, newName) {   

      var b = new File(fileFromPath);
      b.rename(newName);
      
}
```